# Converting Hex to Decimal and merging the result into one cell in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, binary, hex, cell-array

I have the following hex values:

```
 a = '55 D1 1F 81'; 
 b = '9A D2 1F 81'; 
 c = 'EF D3 1F 81'; 
 d = '79 D4 1F 81';
```

and I wish to convert them into binary and then to decimal.
the way I would like the result is as shown below.

[image]

I also have written a code. However it does not give me the required result.

It converts the data into binary but flips the binary values and then messes up the final decimal result.

Here is the code:

```
 a = '55 D1 1F 81'; 
 b = '9A D2 1F 81'; 
 c = 'EF D3 1F 81'; 
 d = '79 D4 1F 81';


s = {a;b;c;d};

%s = cellfun(@strsplit, s, 'UniformOutput', false);
s = regexp(s,'(\w)','match');    
s = vertcat(s{:});
%s = fliplr(s);

% Iterate over each row
for rowNum = 1:size(s,1)

    % To build up binary string from left to right
    binaryString = [];

    % Iterate over each column
    for colNum = 1:size(s,2)

        % Convert hex -> dec -> 8-bit binary word        
        outputBin = dec2bin(hex2dec(s{rowNum,end+1-colNum}), 4);
        binaryString = [binaryString, outputBin]; 

        % Save solution to output array:
        outputBinary{rowNum, colNum} = binaryString;
        outputDec(rowNum, colNum) = bin2dec(binaryString);
    end
end
```

Can anybody please help me in fixing this problem?

Comment: For the part 1) instead of `s = cellfun(@strsplit, s, 'UniformOutput', false);` you can use `s = regexp(s,'(\w)','match')` it will split all the character

Comment: @obchardon Thank you for that line. It splits up all the characters and further changing `outputBin = dec2bin(hex2dec(s{rowNum,end+1-colNum}), 4);` from 8 to 4 works. But my final result is still messed up.

Comment: Can you help me with that please. The values are being converted perfectly, just the arrangement of those binary values is messing up the decimal result

Comment: `a b c` and `d` have always the same size ?

Comment: @obchardon Yes. They will always have the same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
function C = HDB(s) %Hex Dec Bin
   s   = regexp(s,'(\w)','match'); 
   c1  = flip([s{:}].');
   len = 1:length(c1);

   hex   = arrayfun(@(x) c1(1:x).',len,'UniformOutput',0)
   C.hex = arrayfun(@(x) flip(hex{x}),len,'UniformOutput',0)
   C.dec = arrayfun(@(x) hex2dec(C.hex{x}),len,'UniformOutput',0)
   C.bin = arrayfun(@(x) dec2bin(C.dec{x}),len,'UniformOutput',0)
end
```

For example for you array `a` you can use:

```
C = HDB(a)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
hex = 
{
  [1,1] = 1
  [1,2] = 81
  [1,3] = F81
  [1,4] = 1F81
  [1,5] = 11F81
  [1,6] = D11F81
  [1,7] = 5D11F81
  [1,8] = 55D11F81
}
dec = 
{
  [1,1] =  1
  [1,2] =  129
  [1,3] =  3969
  [1,4] =  8065
  [1,5] =  73601
  [1,6] =  13705089
  [1,7] =  97591169
  [1,8] =  1.4398e+09
}
bin = 
{
  [1,1] = 1
  [1,2] = 10000001
  [1,3] = 111110000001
  [1,4] = 1111110000001
  [1,5] = 10001111110000001
  [1,6] = 110100010001111110000001
  [1,7] = 101110100010001111110000001
  [1,8] = 1010101110100010001111110000001
}
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you. But, can you please tell me how can I apply it to a series of data. Because I have 100-300 lines, with the same size. Like in the question, I have mentioned only 4 lines. It's a huge list

Comment: Simply use a for loop ? no ?

Comment: I am sorry if I am asking too much. but could you please show me how.

Comment: I get confused with structures.

Comment: Use for example: `s{1} = '55 D1 1F 81';` 
 `s{2} = '9A D2 1F 81';` 
 
 `for i = 1:length(s)
     C{i} = HDB(s{i});
 end` Read the doc about structures